# Radio button spaces of leftDrawable & rightDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a `RadioGroup` with radio buttons:

```
  <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" 
     >


        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:checked="true" 
            android:text="AAA" 
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_icon"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:drawablePadding="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/radio2"/>

        <RadioButton.../>
    </RadioGroup>
```

As you see above, for the `RadioButton` I defined the following attributes:

```
...
android:button="@null"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_icon"
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
 ...
```

So that the **radio button** is located on the **right** side of the **radio button text**. The left side of button text is a flag icon.

In order to have spaces between button text and flag icon and button icon, I use `android:drawablePadding="60dp"` to space them.

However, with above code, the `60dp` padding space is applied to both **left drawable** (flag icon) and **right drawable** (radio button), which ends up with radio text located in the middle between the two drawables.

I would like to have **radio button text** and **left drawable**(flag icon) has smaller space between, while **radio button text** and **right drawable** (radio button) has larger space between. **How to define the different spaces for left drawable and right drawable of radio button ?**

Answer (score 4):

Simply check this:

```
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                style="@style/my_recording_title_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/presets_sel"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Play with EarPhones" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/line" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                style="@style/my_recording_title_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/presets_sel"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Play with internal speakers" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, android:padding gives space between button and text, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this xml file or add Property  **android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"** or **android:gravity="center"** in your **Radio Button** and remove `padding`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo"
            android:button="@null"            
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing comes up often. And the sad truth is that the limitations of using RadioGroup with RadioButtons **severely** limit your ability to make your layouts look right.

I posted a [very detailed solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996015/changing-the-position-of-radio-button/13299652#13299652) that involves abandoning RadioGroups. I know it seems like a lot of work, but the code is very straight-forward. Until RadioGroups are implemented in a better fashion, this is the best solution I've found.

Good luck!